# Shortening a script, and making it easy to add new variables for the future

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I have made a script that deletes some registry keys. I have set all the key-names as variables, and the destination that leads to them as variables too.

I have added 3 destinations as variables, where I want the same registry-keys to be deleted in all 3 destinations.

As I am beginner at batch, I have not been able to make a sophisticated script, and the commands needed to delete all these registry-keys in all these 3 destinations, turn out to be really long and clumsy to say the least.

I also need this code to be future-secured, so in case we need a new registry key deleted in these 3 destinations, we'll be able to just add a new REG_KEY variable, and it will still work. Just another minor change to the code would be fine too.

Could anyone help me shorten it down somehow? You'll get an idea looking here: http://pastebin.com/VnA16y5i

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set REG_KEY  2^>nul') do set "%%a="
    for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set REG_PATH 2^>nul') do set "%%a="

    SET "REG_KEY01={0EA09877-34E9-4160-B2DE-E7C7703E49ED}"
    SET "REG_KEY02={2F3A6749-B379-4879-9AF8-5C0F04084C74}"
    SET "REG_KEY03={350612EB-55FE-47DC-8E07-197B2409909B}"
    SET "REG_KEY04={628ED0F8-590B-49CF-A525-A1696BD79304}"
    SET "REG_KEY05={69BCC264-0D43-469F-8434-31E738982E7B}"
    SET "REG_KEY06={80416A15-214B-4F25-A025-ED6E875631F2}"
    SET "REG_KEY07={8EC141DE-D310-4A57-B363-02E00627B3F0}"
    SET "REG_KEY08={8EC376A3-F279-47D7-97AA-7BA2A2EB006E}"
    SET "REG_KEY09={915EABF2-2C1A-45C3-89DF-067C1AD39649}"
    SET "REG_KEY10={9AA9FEE7-9F99-4E69-947A-49F7DA0DDA3A}"
    SET "REG_KEY11={A43014F4-44F8-4539-8F87-C8471CB810B1}"
    SET "REG_KEY12={B242E104-74A3-4A32-B665-58677B671A9C}"
    SET "REG_KEY13={F63E747C-5B51-4A6E-9413-BF258F4653F3}"
    SET "REG_KEY14={AAAB700A-DDB7-4298-AB4B-B6E9F785059C}"

    SET "REG_PATH00=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components"
    SET "REG_PATH01=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\LZMA"
    SET "REG_PATH02=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%o in ('set REG_PATH'
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%j in ('set REG_KEY'
    ) do echo reg delete "%%p\%%k" /f /va
```

This code retrieves the content from the environment variables using two `set` commands, one `set REG_PATH` command to retrive the paths and, for each of the paths, a `set REG_KEY` to retrieve the list of the keys. The output lines are splitted to separate the name of the variable and the value inside it.

To ease the management, variable numbers have been padded to ensure the order of execution match the definition order.

`reg delete` operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Comment: Hi, many thanks! I really like this solution. Simple, and you only have to change the variable for it to work, just like I wanted it. However, it seems that it tries to delete each registry key twice in each destination. Any reason for this, or can it be changed to only run once in each destination?

Comment: @ShadowSF96, it seems that you still have the variables in your original code defined into the environment. I've included two lines at the start of the batch file to remove previous values before starting to assign the keys.

Comment: Ah, you are totally right. I hadn't tried using a new command prompt. My mistake. Your script works absolutely brilliantly, and I'll use this one for my final product. @Magoo's script is great too, but I prefer this as you only need to have one file. Many thanks for all you help, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (regkeys.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (regpaths.txt) DO (
  ECHO(reg delete "%%b\%%a" /f /va  
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Where `regkeys.txt` contains

```
{0EA09877-34E9-4160-B2DE-E7C7703E49ED}
{2F3A6749-B379-4879-9AF8-5C0F04084C74}
{350612EB-55FE-47DC-8E07-197B2409909B}
{628ED0F8-590B-49CF-A525-A1696BD79304}
...etc...
```

And `regpaths.txt` contains

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Caphyon\Advanced Installer\LZMA
...etc...
```

Result: simpy add the required new key/path to the files to expand the purge.

Use with caution, obviously. Note that the required commands would simply be `echo`ed. Change `ECHO(reg` **after verification** to `reg` to activate the reg delete...

Comment: Thank you for this solution, simple and easy to use for people with not as much knowledge with batch! Has been added to my considerations, thanks a lot!